Unable to login to OpenSearch dashboard on multi-node with SSL
OpenSearch with SSL enabled on single node is working fine with following docker-compose.yml. However, adding multi-node options (marked with # MULTI-NODE) makes the dashboard stay on the login screen without any error.
services:
  opensearch-node1:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch:${OPENSEARCH_VERSION_TAG}
    container_name: opensearch-node1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster
      - node.name=opensearch-node1 # Name the node that will run in this container
      - discovery.type=single-node
      #- discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2 # MULTI-NODE
      #- cluster.initial_cluster_manager_nodes=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2 # MULTI-NODE
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - OPENSEARCH_INITIAL_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${OPENSEARCH_INITIAL_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      - plugins.security.ssl.transport.pemcert_filepath=node1.pem
      - plugins.security.ssl.transport.pemkey_filepath=node1-key.pem
      - plugins.security.ssl.transport.pemtrustedcas_filepath=root-ca.pem
      - plugins.security.ssl.transport.enforce_hostname_verification=false
      - plugins.security.ssl.http.enabled=true
      - plugins.security.ssl.http.pemcert_filepath=node1.pem
      - plugins.security.ssl.http.pemkey_filepath=node1-key.pem
      - plugins.security.ssl.http.pemtrustedcas_filepath=root-ca.pem
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_SHARED_DIR}/data/opensearch/node1:/usr/share/opensearch/data
      - ${HOST_SHARED_DIR}/certs/node1.pem:/usr/share/opensearch/config/node1.pem
      - ${HOST_SHARED_DIR}/certs/node1-key.pem:/usr/share/opensearch/config/node1-key.pem
      - ${HOST_SHARED_DIR}/certs/root-ca.pem:/usr/share/opensearch/config/root-ca.pem
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9600:9600

  # MULTI-NODE
  #opensearch-node2:
  #   image: opensearchproject/opensearch:${OPENSEARCH_VERSION_TAG}
  #   container_name: opensearch-node2
  #   environment:
  #     - cluster.name=opensearch-cluster
  #     - node.name=opensearch-node2
  #     - discovery.seed_hosts=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2
  #     - cluster.initial_cluster_manager_nodes=opensearch-node1,opensearch-node2
  #     - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
  #     - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
  #     - OPENSEARCH_INITIAL_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${OPENSEARCH_INITIAL_ADMIN_PASSWORD}
  #     - plugins.security.ssl.transport.pemcert_filepath=node2.pem
  #     - plugins.security.ssl.transport.pemkey_filepath=node2-key.pem
  #     - plugins.security.ssl.transport.pemtrustedcas_filepath=root-ca.pem
  #     - plugins.security.ssl.transport.enforce_hostname_verification=false
  #     - plugins.security.ssl.http.enabled=true
  #     - plugins.security.ssl.http.pemcert_filepath=node2.pem
  #     - plugins.security.ssl.http.pemkey_filepath=node2-key.pem
  #     - plugins.security.ssl.http.pemtrustedcas_filepath=root-ca.pem

  opensearch-dashboards:
    image: opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:${OPENSEARCH_VERSION_TAG}
    container_name: opensearch-dashboards
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    depends_on:
      - opensearch-node1
      #- opensearch-node1 # MULTI-NODE
    environment:
      - OPENSEARCH_HOSTS=["https://opensearch-node1:9200"]
      #- OPENSEARCH_HOSTS=["https://opensearch-node1:9200","https://opensearch-node2:9200"] # MULTI-NODE

The error log for opensearch-dashboards container show the following upon startup
2024-07-01 12:02:40 {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2024-07-01T17:02:40Z","tags":["error","opensearch","data"],"pid":1,"message":"[ConnectionError]: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.29.0.3:9200"}

localhost:5601 throws the following error
{"statusCode":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"An internal server error occurred."}

Please note that if I disable the SSL and remove security certificates, everything works as expected with multi-node setup as well.
